# Можно ли объединить ResNet с Graph Attention Network?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, компьютерное-зрение

Я занимаюсь анти-спуфингом лиц.
У меня есть графовая сеть на внимании (Graph Attention Network), которую я взял здесь https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.05544.pdf и применил ее к задаче анти-спуфинга лиц.
Помимо этого мне нужно сделать комбинацию ResNet и Graph Attention Network как вот здесь https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.03654.pdf

Вопрос: могу ли я сделать такую комбинацию для задачи анти-спуфинга лиц?
Или я могу использовать только Graph Attention Network.

Мой преподаватель сказал, что можно сделать ResNet + GAT, но ResNet без последних двух слоев.